# Error GET http://localhost:4200/styles.css but I'm able to use these styles. Whats the deal?

Tags: html, angular

I'm receiving an error in my angular 2 project where in the chrome developer tools console there is a message saying GET http://localhost:4200/styles.css with a red x to the left of it. I'm able to use these styles though so what's the deal?

This is my index.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Scorekeeper</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Clear your browser cache and see if you still can use the style

Comment: Did what you said and I can still use the styles.

Comment: Is it possible that the styles that your are using, actually exist in the other css files that you have in the header?

Comment: I don't think so.  I can change a rule in my styles.css and see that change reflected on page refresh.

Comment: In IE, if you open the developer tools and go to the 'Elements' tab, in the 'Styles' tab, it actually shows the css file name that holds the style. You can check that too.

Comment: Inside of my styles.css I have defined one h4 rule as having a padding of 15px. I inspect the h4 elements and indeed it has the 15px rule but it says they aren't coming from a file, rather a <style></style> tag. And no I don't have any inline style tags anywhere in my project so I'm confused.

Comment: Point your assets folder

Comment: are you using angular cli?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Remove that link to your stylesheet from your index.html. You're using the angular-cli and in your configuration, styles.css is being included by the angular-cli. Your link tag in the HTML isn't doing anything.

(The angular cli is also dynamically injecting a link tag for that style into your html, which is why 'it works').

Comment: Thanks! Lol, did you know that the official tutorial advised us to include it? :sigh:

Answer (score 5):

Remove your styleSheet path from index.html and link it through angular-cli.json like this
 styles:

```
 [
        "styles.css",
        "css/style.css",
        "css-link/bootstrap.css"
       ]
```

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)